# Install libstdc++ 4.9.x from source but compiled with glibc 2.14

Tags: rhel, libraries, source-code

I am on a

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
Linux version 2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64 
(mockbuild@x86-042.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) 
(gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jan 12 15:07:59 EST 2018
```

box without admin rights. From various applications/install scripts I get

```
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by...
```

(e.g. from jupyter notebook)

My gcc version is `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5` and from `strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` I get `GLIBCXX_3.4.13` as the latest version.

I have already installed `glibc 2.14` from source and have it on my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so according to [the answer here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/searching-for-glibcxx_3-4-20-a-4175552395/) I need to install

```
libstdc++-4.9.x, which is compiled with glibc-2.14
```

unfortunately I cannot find that on `rpmfind`.

Comment: The object GLIBCXX_3.4.20 in libstdc++ version 4.9.x : Doesn't need to be compiled with a particular glibc version. The gcc-4.9.x available for EL6 was once compiled with a default RHEL6 ... and includes libstdc++ v. 4.9: `/usr/local/gcc493/lib64/{ libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.20 }`. You can point to this libstdc++.so.6, when running the applications. See 3) gcc49-c++-4.9.3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915

Comment: sorry I don't understand, when I `strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` I only find `GLIBCXX_3.4.13` (the same in `/usr/lib/` and also for `libstdc++.so.6.0.13`. I currently have `libstdc++.so.6` on my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and get the error described above

Comment: ? Who mentioned `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` ? Download `gcc49-c++-4.9.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`. You can install the package with yum: `# yum install Downloads/gcc49-c++-4.9.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` ... or you can unpack the package, and use { libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.20 } only.  "unPack_rpm.sh" https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3d9QqrRhEThYByPDgWEaoxHnqWFWqfE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KnudLarsen thanks for clarifying. the download link for gcc49 is blocked for me. I have searched for 2h but didnt find gcc 4.9 source for el6 on sites that I could access. Is it somewhere on rpmfind or rpm pbone?

Comment: `gcc49-c++-4.9.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` → Other link →   https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dbj5jjwrk4iapz/gcc49-c%2B%2B-4.9.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm?dl=0